# how to update a text file in a loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, text-mining

I write a function that can update a text file only for once but I need to repeatedly do it . In order to avoid frequently copy a temporary file to a target file , I want to   update all words  in a loop for only once .How can i can do it?
Here is my python code(but only update once):

```
import io
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
from os import remove, close

def replaceWords(source_file_path, old_word, cluster_labels):

    new_word_list = [old_word + "_" + str(label) for label in cluster_labels]
    fh, target_file_path = mkstemp()

    with io.open(target_file_path, mode='w', encoding='utf8') as target_file:
        with io.open(source_file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as source_file:
            index = 0
            for line in source_file:
                words =[]
                for word in line.split():
                    if word == old_word:
                        words.append(word.replace(old_word, new_word_list[index]))
                        index += 1
                    else:
                        words.append(word)
                target_file.write(" ".join(words))

    close(fh)
    remove(source_file_path)
    move(target_file_path, source_file_path)
```

for example:

for the first update:

source file contexts :`of anarchism have often been divided into the categories of social and individualist anarchism or similar dual classifications`

old_word: 'of'

cluster_labels: '[1, 2]'

after update:
target file contexts :`of_1 anarchism have often been divided into the categories of_2 social and individualist anarchism or similar dual classifications`

for the second update :

old_word: 'anarchism'

cluster_labels: '[1, 2]'

after update:

target file contexts :`of_1 anarchism_1 have often been divided into the categories of_2 social and individualist anarchism_2 or similar dual classifications`

In my code , I have to call the function two times and copy file two times, but when the words needed to be updated are too many, this method is definitely time-consuming and frequent reading/writing/copying which is io unfriendly.

**so, is there any method that can elegantly deal with this without frequently reading/writing/copying?**

Answer (score 0):

There can be many way to do this. 1 of the approach inline to what you have done can be to use *argv to get the list of words to be replaced and replace the words in same line as you are doing currenty.  I am adding kind of pseudo code here, it is not tested for the errors.
Please note 2 changes 
1. in the input parameter to the function. 
2. added the for loop to iterate through the input parameter.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import io
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
from os import remove, close
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s -%(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def replaceWords(**source_file_path, cluster_labels ,*argv**):
    old_word = 'of'
    new_word_list = [old_word + "_" + str(label) for label in cluster_labels]
    fh, target_file_path = mkstemp()
    logging.debug(new_word_list)
    logging.debug(old_word)

    with io.open(target_file_path, mode='w', encoding='utf8') as target_file:
        with io.open(source_file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as source_file:
            index = 0
            for line in source_file:
                words =[]
                for word in line.split():
                        **for wordtochange in argv:**
                                if word == old_word:
                                        words.append(word.replace(old_word, new_word_list[index]))
                                        index += 1
                                else:
                                        words.append(word)
                target_file.write(" ".join(words))

    close(fh)
    remove(source_file_path)
    move(target_file_path, source_file_path)

replaceWords('file.txt',[1,2],('of','anarchism'))
```